# How to use Future Delayed

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 2 functions. I want to run them one by one but while the first function is done, the second function must wait for 1-2 seconds. I tried Future.delayed for this but it did not work. It changes nothing.

```
void kartat(int tip, int deger, int mainid, List mycards) {
    masadakicards.add(cardbank[mainid]);
    print("kart atıldı");
    rakipkartat(51);

  }

  void rakipkartat(int mainid) {
    new Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      // deleayed code here
      masadakicards.add(cardbank[mainid]);
      print("ann");
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A way that you can achieve this is by using `await Future.delayed`

make sure that your method is returns a `Future`

```dart
Future<void> start() async {
  await foo();
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
  await bar();
}

Future<void> foo() async {
  print('foo started');
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  print('foo executed');
  return;
}

Future<void> bar() async {
  print('bar started');
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  print('bar executed');
  return;
}
```

expected:

```
foo started
   - waits 1 second -
foo executed
    - waits 2 seconds -
bar started
    - waits 1 second -
bar executed
```

Following your methods

Please note that the method that gets executed after the delay also needs to include `async` and `await`, otherwise the method will run synchronously and not await the Future.

```dart
Future<void> start() async {
  foo();
}

void foo() {
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () async {
    // do something here
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    // do stuff
  });
}
```

Comment: It works but the changes doesn't see on the simulator. When i delete to the delayed part ,  it works fine. ( I'm working on a card game application.)

Comment: If you're updating the data and it is being displayed as UI, it sounds like you need to be using a stateful widget and setState. You mentioned that the change only happens after you hot reload, this would make sense because you are updating the UI and the widget's state.

Comment: But i cant use setState in my dart class :( is there any other solution?

Comment: If you're trying to show updates to your UI by adding to your list of data, you will need to use `setState` or a state manager (like BLoC or Provider/RiverPod). You can't display updates to your UI unless you update the state.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your overall approach is appropriate (can't tell from this), however,
`Future<void> rakipkartat(int mainid) async {` should do.

I guess it would be better if you create both and the calling function as Future and then call the functions with `await kartet(); await rakipkartat()`

By the way, implementing my 1st paragraph also requests that the calling function is a Future or at least handles the call as a Future.

Comment: I just want the rakipkartat function waits 2 seconds. Await async didn't work :(

Comment: what is the error? You have to make rakipkartat a future and you either need a future builder in your calling class/function or you have to make the calling function also a future async. Maybe you have look into some examples around Future

Comment: There is no error. Nothing happens. It works only when i click hot reload button.. :(

Comment: Does it look like Morgan's snippet? If you add some print statements (also within what Morgan called start() async {}) you might find the spot where your code fails - or you use the debugger. Unfortunately, fetching data often fails silently

Comment: It prints , also it adds an item to the list. But when i put the delayed part , the changes doesn't seen on the simulator.